# Deleting (12) from Df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bigger df with several columns having values like: 12(1).
df.dtypes shows these columns are objects. I tried

`df['Age'] = df['Age'].str.strip()`

with out success. Added a code down low but it does not work when I add ()......
Any idea what I could do to change the values in the columns?

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish', 'Jack'],
        'Age':['20 (1)', '21 (3)', '19 (2)', '18 (1)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace`. Unlike to `str.replace`, `replace` apply modifications in all columns.

```
>>> df.replace('\s*\(.*\)$', '', regex=True)
    Name Age
0    Tom  20
1   Nick  21
2  Krish  19
3   Jack  18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do so.

```
patter = r"\(\d+\)"
df["Age"] = df["Age"].str.replace(patter, "", regex=True).astype(int)
```

The `pattern` variable matches any number of digits inside parentheses. Then you replace it with empty string. Finally, you convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Mmh, I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you want the number only, you could use several ways like:

```
df["Age"] = df["Age"].str.extract(r"(^\d+)")
df["Age"] = df["Age"].str.split(" ").str[0]
```

The first way uses regex to say start of line (`^`) and one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`).
The second uses str.split, which splits the string at the first space. `.str[0]` gets the first position in the list after the split.

If you want to do it for the whole DataFrame, you can use

```
df = df.replace(r" ?\(.*\)$", "", regex=True)
```

which looks for an optional space  `?`, brackets `\(` `\)` (need to be escaped, as they are capture groups otherwise) and some arbitrary text in brackets `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["23(1.1)", "30(1.3)", "32"],
    ["23(1.2)", "31(1.6)", "31(1.2)"],
    ], columns=[f"col{i}" for i in range(1,4)])

selected_cols = ['col1', 'col2']
for col in selected_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].replace(r"\(.*\)", "", regex=True)
```